# how to extract web address from a string in php

Tags: php, regex

I know how to extract web address from `url` like this:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j__wz7NtNgM

I can extract "youtube.com" from it.

I have no idea how to extract web address from  a string like this

> my fav website is youtube.com snel ip

How to extract "youtube.com" from it?

Comment: Try `echo parse_url("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j__wz7NtNgM",PHP_URL_HOST);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use different functions. 
There are:

1. [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
2. [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)
3. [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

I suggest you using the parse_url function, you can work with it more easy. 
To check the url with the preg_match function you have to declare the whole 
regex of a url. With the trim function you can split the parts off, 
e.g. the http://xxx part or the part behind this section

Comment: OP has URL embedded in a larger string, `parse_url` will not help.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you’re implementing it in PHP, it’s rather a question of regular expression, right?

Just like a complete URL, you can match the fragment of hostname and TLD from any text. The former’s got the advantage that, to put it a bit bluntly, it starts with `https?` which can’t be mistaken so easily. On the other hand, it’s hard to tell apart if it’s a web address or if someone just missed hitting space:

> my fav website is **youtube.com** snel ip and it **blows[.museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.museum)** is closed, right?

One possible trade-off is by detecting addresses that start with either a protocol or a dubdubdub:

```
(https?:\/\/([a-z]+\.)*|www\.)([a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,})(\/)?
```

That’s a bit safer, but it won’t match your example. So, another imperfect way is to detect links if they have some sort of boundary around them:

```
(^|\b|\s)([a-z0-9]+\.[a-z]{2,})(\b|\W|$)
```

You could narrow mismatches by making a whitelist of TLDs like `(com|net)`, but I’d not do that; remember there’s [IDNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name). If you wish to support something like [http://موقع.وزارة-الاتصالات.مصر/](http://xn--4gbrim.xn----ymcbaaajlc6dj7bxne2c.xn--wgbh1c/), it gets a bit more sophisticated.

The regular expressions above do work, though their intent is to be a mere lead to further adjust to your needs and to propose another solution respectively.